# SQL query to get the employee who has not been appraised

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a employees salary history table, sal_hist which has id,name, salary and effective_date. Requirement is to get the employee who has not been appraised. Below is the table:

| Id | name | salary | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1000 | 10-5-2020 |
| 1 | a | 2000 | 12-6-2020 |
| 1 | a | 3000 | 12-7-2020 |
| 2 | b | 2500 | 12-5-2020 |
| 2 | b | 3500 | 12-7-2020 |
| 3 | c | 2500 | 12-5-2020 |

Below is the query I have:

```
Select id,name from sal_hist group by id,name having count(1)=1;
```

Is there a different way to achieve the result?

Comment: What does "appraised" have to do with this table?

Comment: What do you mean by *different* way?  Is this something wrong with the way you already have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `date` column is the appraisal date and you want the user who has not got an appraisal at the latest date then:

```sql
SELECT id, name, salary, appraisal_date
FROM   (
  SELECT s.*,
         MAX(appraisal_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS max_user_appraisal_date,
         MAX(appraisal_date) OVER () AS max_appraisal_date
  FROM   salary_history s
)
WHERE appraisal_date = max_user_appraisal_date
AND   max_user_appraisal_date < max_appraisal_date
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE salary_history (Id, name, salary, appraisal_date) AS
SELECT 1, 'a', 1000, DATE '2020-05-10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'a', 2000, DATE '2020-06-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'a', 3000, DATE '2020-07-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b', 2500, DATE '2020-05-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b', 3500, DATE '2020-07-12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'c', 2500, DATE '2020-05-12' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | NAME | SALARY | APPRAISAL_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | c | 2500 | 12-MAY-20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8efd2edf58c2b6ffa9fba5b940c48182)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for another way to achieve the result and find the employee with only 1 salary listed (no appraisals in the past) you can use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM (
SELECT id, name, COUNT(id) AS [count]
FROM sal_hist 
GROUP BY id,name) 
WHERE count=1;
```

But I would note that using `HAVING` as you have currently is a better method.